# Identify kiosk app version via Directory API

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Is there a way to access information, specifially the version, of the installed kiosk app on a managed Chrome device? The chromeosdevices API has the OS version, but no mention of the kiosk app.

The lack of information itself should be an answer to this, but I wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to determine the extension version running on a given device remotely though assuming you control the extension, you could have it report back to your servers the current version.

Comment: Thanks Jay, is there a feature request system so this might be added?

Comment: You can file an FR at crbug.com. If you've purchased licenses you can also submit a support ticket asking for the feature to be added.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go via the Chrome for Work dashboard